# Download the content of a file on my server google drive php sdk

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using google drive php sdk to get the content of the files on google drive but i am not understanding that how can i download the content i tried this function

```
function downloadFile($service, $file) 
                        {

                            if ($file) {
                              $request = new Google_HttpRequest($file, 'GET', null, null);
                             $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
                             echo $httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode();
                              if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
                                return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
                              } else {
                                // An error occurred.
                                //return null;
                                 //echo "error";
                                 print_r($httpRequest);
                              }
                            } else {
                              // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                              return null;
                            }
                          }
```

calling this function like this

```
$down=downloadFile($service, $divefl['webContentLink']);
```

if i pass webContentLink link it is giving the response code 302 that means file temperately moved . and if i pass alternateLink it is giving an error code 401 i.e unauthorize . please help me how can i get the content

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the downloadURL.
If you provide webContentLink, this is if you want to create a link in the browser and locally download this file.

Unfortunately in my system this didn't work either, since the API has changed.